# BitTest search in BigQuery (by position)

Tags: google-bigquery, binary-search

I keep number representation of binary data in BigQuery table

I need to be able to search by BitPos and find out if bit on given position in  0 or 1

Oracle analog is BitTest

`Use this function to return TRUE (1) if the specified bit in a value is a 1; otherwise return FALSE (0).
Syntax BitTest(Value1, BitPos)`

Example: number in DB is 1099511627780

So it is binary `10000000000000000000000000000000000000100`

Thus Results are:

`BitTest(1099511627780, 1) = 0;`

`BitTest(1099511627780, 2) = 0;`

`BitTest(1099511627780, 3) = 1;`

Can you help me to find native implementation in BigQuery?

I was looking through doc with no luck

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a temporary function that performs this computation using a bit shift and bitwise and. Here is an example:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION BitTest(value INT64, bit INT64) AS (
  value >> (bit - 1) & 0x1 = 1
);

SELECT
  value,
  bit,
  BitTest(value, bit) AS result
FROM (
  SELECT 1099511627780 AS value, bit
  FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1, 42)) AS bit
)
ORDER BY bit;
```

The function `BitTest` checks whether the bit at the 1-based index is set. The `FROM` clause in this example generates bit indexes between 1 and 42 to demonstrate what the output is.

Comment: `SELECT
  art_design_android,
  COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM
  [bridge_prod_dataset.MASTER_TABLE]  
  WHERE   art_design_android & 384 = 384
  GROUP BY art_design_android`

Comment: 384  = 110000000, so SQL returns all numbers where bit 10 and 11 are 1

Comment: your version is an amazing  polyfill!

Comment: Query Failed in BQ console
@elliott-brossard 

`Error: Encountered " "CREATE" "CREATE "" at line 1, column 1. Was expecting: <EOF>
Job ID: eminent-torch-384:bquijob_f8d277_160b79f285e`

Comment: I thought that you were using standard SQL based on the link in your question. In the UI, you need to [enable standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/enabling-standard-sql). You can also consider signing up for the [UI alpha](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSf6hyfvoWZ8eUbbKWq9fzVfj7ljVyl2SdhtWH038Xrx2eHVrw/viewform), where standard SQL is the default.

Comment: Thanks! How to do  CREATE TEMP FUNCTION using BQL?

Comment: What is BQL? If you are referring to legacy SQL, you can't use `CREATE TEMP FUNCTION`. Please use standard SQL instead.

Comment: so there is no way to use  bigquery.defineFunction via API?

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/user-defined-functions

Comment: You send the `CREATE TEMP FUNCTION` statement as part of the query text itself, not through a side-channel as with legacy SQL.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162362/discussion-between-lev-savranskiy-and-elliott-brossard).

Comment: I think my answer was sufficient to address your original question. If you have a different question about how user-defined functions work, please post a separate question.